# Python web scrape from asx - could not get the announcement table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape announcement table from asx page, however, when I use BeautifulSoup to parse html, this table is not there.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www2.asx.com.au/markets/trade-our-cash-market/announcements.cba'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')
```

the above code returns nothing in `table`, but this is a announcement table in the webpage, how to scrape the table?

[image]

Comment: call the backend `API` --> https://asx.api.markitdigital.com/asx-research/1.0/markets/announcements?entityXids[]=204245597&page=0&itemsPerPage=25&summaryCountsDate=2021-02-26

Answer (score 1):

The data is dynamically loaded. Use selenium or another program that will allow the content to load, then pass to bs4. You'll need to load selenium and download chromedriver.exe

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://www2.asx.com.au/markets/trade-our-cash-market/announcements.cba'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup.find_all('table') # you should get a list of size one; if there is only one table, you might just want to use find instead
```